# 'React' is defined but never used - what could be the issue?

Tags: reactjs, python-3.x, flask, vite

I am writing a python + React contact app using vite and flask and i keep experiencing this error that says 'React' is defined but never used.This is my code:

This is App.jsx

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import ContactList from './ContactList';

function App() {
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);


  useEffect(() => {
    fetchContacts()
  }, []);

  const fetchContacts = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/contacts");
    const data = await response.json();
    setContacts(data.contacts);
  };

  return (
    <ContactList contacts={contacts} />
  );
}

export default App
```

This is contact.jsx

```
import React from 'react'

const ContactList = ({contacts}) => {
  return (
    <div>
        <h2>Contacts</h2>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {contacts.map((contact) => (
                    <tr key={contact.id}>
                        <td>{contact.firstName}</td>
                        <td>{contact.lastName}</td>
                        <td>{contact.email}</td>
                        <td>
                            <button>Update</button>
                            <button>Delete</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                ))}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

  )
}

export default ContactList;
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0,eslint src/**/*.js src/**/*.jsx",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.56",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.19",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.5",
    "vite": "^5.1.4"
  }
}
```

What could be the issue?

So I run "npm i" on the frontend to import React but for some reason unknown to me, i keep having this error

Answer (score 0):

Remove import React from 'react' statement from contact.jsx file